Non-Abelian group of order $21$ subgroups
This is an exam problem from a couple of years ago...
I)Let $G$ be a nonabelian group of order $21$. What are the possible orders of
elements of $G$?
II)Find the number of Sylow $p$–subgroups of G, for each prime $p$.
III)Determine how many elements $G$ has of each order.
IV)Does $G$ have any other proper, nontrivial subgroups?
My solution:
i) Possible orders of elements are $1,3,7,21$ as these are the divisors of $21$
ii) There is one of each Syllow $p$-subgroup, as other alternatives would exceed the order of $21$
iii) In each $p$-subgroup there are $p-1$ elements of order $p$, so $2$ and $6$
iv) This is the one I am struggling with. My guess is that there are no other proper non-trivial subgroups because their order would have to divide $21$ by Lagrange.
Is my reasoning corect so far?

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

Please ask one question at a time.

The group is nonabelian and hence not cyclic; it is also finite; it cannot, therefore, have an element of order $|G|=21$.

For $(iv)$ : By Lagrange theorem, a non-trivial subgroup of $G$ has order $3,7$ or $21$, the previous questions allow you to find what are the subgroups of $G$ of order $3$ and $7$.

See the tag wiki for links to meta discussions.

I) Your answer is not correct. 21 is ruled out because G is nonabelian, whereas subgroups of order 3 and 7 exist by Cauchy's theorem (or, more elementarily, because the nontrivial elements must have some order and they cannot be only order 3 or order 7, by the class equation).
II) Your answer is not correct. The Sylow 7-subgroup is unique by a counting argument (even regardless of Sylow III), but Sylow 3-subgroups must be seven, as otherwise G would be abelian.
III) According to II), there are (7-1).1=6 elements of order 7 and (3-1).7=14 elements of order 3.
IV) Here you are correct, because there aren't any other proper divisors of 21.

But if there are seven Sylow 3-subgroups that would exceed the maximal number of elements, as $3  \times 6 = 18$ and plus the extra 7…we exclude the identity in the other 6

As for the Sylow 3-subgroups, the right counting is $(3-1)\times 7= 14$ elements of order 3, as the identity is in all of them.

Right, my bad. Yes, $14$ elements of order 3, and $6$ of order 7, we add the identity to that
